# Airpods not appearing in Bluetooth (Yet again!)

Tags: bluetooth, airpods

- I've opened Bluetooth.
- Opened the Airpod lid
- pressed the Airpod button

Nothing. Why?

This is very frustrating.
I'm in a situation where I need them for a meeting, and Apple technology fails yet again.

Mac 10.15.6

Comment: Were they paired before or is this a new pairing?  Have you confirmed that they are charged?

Comment: Have you any USB 3 devices active?  This can mess up Bluetooth.

Comment: 1. Did you try removing any existing AirPods before pairing? 2. Did you hold down the button with the case open, with the AirPods inside, until the light blinked white?